# iOS: sorting an NSArray of core data objects

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, nsentitydescription

I have a NSArray with core data entities called:

```
"Struct"
```

thy have an attribute called "value" that can be a double

```
Struct *struct = [array objectAtIndex:0];
double val = [struct value];
```

I have to sorting this array by this value but I don't understand what's the way to do it, because I have not a key to access to the object.

Do you have any suggests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSNumber *s1 = @([(Struct *)a value]);
    NSNumber *s2 = @([(Struct *)b value]);
    return [s1 compare:s2];
}];
```

Comment: A `double` is an atomic type (not an object), this code won't compile

Comment: ooo sorry...yesterday i was tired..obviously need to consider as NSNumber. I forgot! Code edited! Sorry guys ahah